# Plotting heatmap on a world map using the latitude, longitude data in python

Tags: python-3.x, plot, latitude-longitude, heatmap

I have latitude, longitude data and a count variable corresponding to that as below:

```
lat      long    count
23.7000  90.3750 45
23.7231  90.4086 1000
```

I want to visualize the counts data(as heatmap) on a dummy world map by identifying the latitude and longitude in the map.

I read that basemap package can do that, but it's not available for python 3.5.

I couldn't find any relevant material, that can help me do this

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using colorbar of matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(lat, long, c=count)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```